# addSubview works on device, crashes on Simulator

Tags: objective-c, ios-simulator

- Development Environment: XCode 5.1

  - Simulator Hardware: iPhone Retina 4-inch
  - Device Hardware: iPhone 5 16Gb

I have this code in Objective-C that works on the Device but it does not on the Simulator sending a EXC_BAD_ACCESS:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        CGSize size = frame.size;

        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.1 green:0.1 blue:0.1 alpha:1]];
        int radius = size.height * 0.3;

        if (radius < 200)
            radius = 200;

        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(size.width * 0.5 - radius * 0.5, size.height * 0.5 - radius * 0.5, radius, radius);

        projectImage = [[UIMaskedImage alloc] initWithImage:[ProjectController getImageForProject:nil] inFrame:rect withTintColor:[UIColor clearColor] anInsetRadius:6];


        int icon_size = 50;
        int icon_margin = 10;

        menuButton = [[UISVGButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(icon_margin, icon_margin, icon_size, icon_size) svgAtPath:@"list.svg" andColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [menuButton addTarget:self action:@selector(closeScene:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self addSubview:menuButton];

        backButton = [[UISVGButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(size.width - icon_size - icon_margin, icon_margin, icon_size, icon_size) svgAtPath:@"arrow_down.svg" andColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

        [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(closeOptionsMenu:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


        int icon2_size = 100;


        shareButton = [[UISVGButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(size.width*0.5 + radius * 0.5 + icon_margin*2,  size.height*0.5 - icon2_size*0.5, icon2_size, icon2_size)  svgAtPath:@"share.svg" andColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

        [shareButton addTarget:self action:@selector(shareOnSocialNetworks:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


        deleteSaveButton = [[UISVGButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(size.width*0.5 - radius * 0.5 - icon_margin*2 -icon2_size, size.height*0.5 - icon2_size*0.5, icon2_size, icon2_size)svgAtPath:@"delete.svg" andColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

        [deleteSaveButton addTarget:self action:@selector(downloadCurrentProject:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


        [self setClipsToBounds:YES];

        [self addSubview:backButton];
        [self addSubview:deleteSaveButton];
        [self addSubview:projectImage];
        [self addSubview:shareButton];
    }
    return self;
}
```

This line crashes:

**[self addSubview:backButton];**

Any suggestion?

Comment: Is backButton a strong reference? You are probably running into a memory management issue here.

Comment: [self.view addSubview:backButton];

Comment: @Rushi, This class is a UIView itself. I cannot add a view using [self.view addSubView:backButton]. Only [self addSubview: backButton]

Comment: @HermannKlecker I tried declaring all Subviews as __weak, but still not working. Memory is only 16MB at this point and CPU 2%.

Comment: in debugger, did you inspect backButton (and self)? Did you try Instruments?

Comment: No, they shoudl be strong because they are allocated within this class and it "owns" them.

Comment: @HermannKlecker you are right. Please add the answer below so I can vote for it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For dynamically (programmatically) allocated UI elements, always keep a strong reference in the view controller that owns them.